# Asterisk inbound call status

Tags: asterisk

I want to make a real time program that shows the inbound calls. The problem is that i don't know where to get the call status, like hold, calling or answered.

Asterisk has a Variable ${CALLERID(num)} to get the number but don't know where to get the rest of the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get it through PHP-AGI. You can connect to Asterisk Cli using this. The command "queue show

http://sysadminman.net/blog/2012/asterisk-elastix-queue-and-agent-wallboard-3604

Hope the above will help

Answer (score 1):

To get information from Asterisk you can use the Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI), there are some information about it available at [the-asterisk-book.com](http://www.the-asterisk-book.com/unstable/asterisk-manager-api.html) and [voip-info.org](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API). Then I am sure you can monitor the status of peers, channels and if they are calling or answering.

I hope this will help you.